# Can we add syntax highlighting to the pennylane tag?

Tags: feature-request

It seems that the [pennylane](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pennylane) tag does not have syntax highlighting (see for instance [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/34065/10454)).

Since Pennylane is a Python framework, is it possible to add syntax highlighting for this tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. Thanks for the pointer. Let me know if other tags need it.